# How I can use the function names with for in R

Tags: r

I have a little problem with my R code. I don't know where, but I make a mistake. 
The problem is:

I have many file excel with the same names of the columns. I'd like to change the titles of the matrix, with a other titles.

These are five files.

```
AA <- read_excel("AA.xlsx") 
BB <- read_excel("BB.xlsx")
CC <- read_excel("CC.xlsx")
DD <- read_excel("DD.xlsx")
EE <- read_excel("EE.xlsx")
```

`head(AA) #the matrix is the same for the other file.
    DATA                Open    Max    Min     Close     VAR % CLOSE   VOLUME
  <dttm>                 <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2004-07-07 00:00:00     3.73    3.79   3.6      3.70          0    21810440
2 2004-07-08 00:00:00     3.7     3.71   3.47     3.65         -1.43  7226890
3 2004-07-09 00:00:00     3.61    3.65   3.56     3.65          0     3754407
4 2004-07-12 00:00:00     3.64    3.65   3.59     3.63         -0.55   850667
5 2004-07-13 00:00:00     3.63    3.63   3.58     3.59         -1.16   777508
6 2004-07-14 00:00:00     3.54    3.59   3.47     3.5          -2.45  1931765`

To change the titles fast, I decided to use this code.

```
t <- list(AA, BB, CC, DD, EE)
for (i in t ) {
names(i) <- c("DATA", "OPE", "MAX", "MIN", "CLO", "VAR%", "VOL")
} #R dosen't give any type of error!


head(AA) #the data are the same, as the for dosen't exits.
```

Where I was wrong?

Thank you so much in advance.

Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `lapply`.  Get the datasets in a `list` with `mget`, loop through the `list`, set the column names to vector of names ('nm1
) and modify the objects in the global environment with `list2env`

```
nm1 <- c("DATA", "OPE", "MAX", "MIN", "CLO", "VAR%", "VOL")
lst <- lapply(mget(nm2), setNames, nm1)
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using a `for` loop, loop through the string of object names and `assign` the column names to the objects in the global environment

```
for(nm in nm2) assign(nm, `names<-`(get(nm), nm1))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(nm2) %>% 
    map(set_names, nm1) %>%
    list2env(., envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
AA <- mtcars[1:7]
BB <- mtcars[1:7]
CC <- mtcars[1:7]
DD <- mtcars[1:7]
EE <- mtcars[1:7]
nm2 <- strrep(LETTERS[1:5], 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to explain why your code didn't work. In the list `t`, the address of `AA` (t[[1]]) is the the same as `AA` in the global environment. In the for-loop, `i` initially is the same copy as the data.frame `AA` in global env. When you change the names of `i` with `names(i) <-`, the data.frame `i` is copied twice. Finally, you are changing the name of a new data.frame `i` rather than the original `data.frame` `AA` in the global environment.

Here is an example to illustrate what I mean (`tracemem` "marks an object so that a message is printed whenever the internal code copies the object."):

```
tracemem(mtcars)
# [1] "<0x1095b2150>"
tracemem(iris)
# [1] "<0x10959a350>"

x <- list(mtcars, iris)

for(i in x){
    cat('-------\n')
    tracemem(i)
    names(i) <- paste(names(i), 'xx')
}
# -------
# tracemem[0x1095b2150 -> 0x10d678c00]: 
# tracemem[0x10d678c00 -> 0x10d678ca8]: 
# -------
# tracemem[0x10959a350 -> 0x10cb307b0]: 
# tracemem[0x10cb307b0 -> 0x10cb30818]:
```